# Facebook post link - image cropping

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After searching tons of sites about this topic I still have no idea what facebooks rules for image cropping are.

The scenario is:
My app posts links though the graph api on behalf of a user and passes pictures which have a resolution of 1200x627px (got the 'new' resolution from here: http://www.jonloomer.com/2013/09/12/facebook-ads-image-dimensions/).

So far so good. In a desktop-browser on the users timeline or on a friends stream the link is shown with a cropped version: 300px from left and right are gone, the image becomes 116x116px thumbnail. I could live with that and respect that in image-design. But...
On my android phone the image is also cropped but differently. There the image is cropped on all sides, leaving out approx. 150px at the top and bottom.
Of course only in the native app :(( If I use the mobile browser-version, the image is shown full - no cropping at all !!??

And if that wasn't enough, it changes when I use a different access-token for publishing!
When I get an access token with the Graph API explorer and publish the exact! same link, message, image... then the image is shown full on desktop browser.

Is there any way to control the cropping? Or does anyone know why changing the access-token results in different behavior?

Thanks in advance.
C.